# Why can't I center a SizeTransition horizontally in a Column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Please check the following code. Regardless what I tried, the SizeTransition is not centered horizontally in the Column. I tried to wrap Column in a Container and then provide infinite width. I tried to wrap SizeTransition in a Center. I tried to wrap SizeTransition in a Container which has center alignment property. I tried to wrap it in a Stack. I tried to give the container child with alignment center property etc... But none of them works...

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: AnimatedBox(),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedBox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _AnimatedBoxState();
}

class _AnimatedBoxState extends State<AnimatedBox> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('animate forward'),
          onPressed: () {_controller.forward();},
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('animate reverse'),
          onPressed: () {_controller.reverse();},
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 100.0,),
        SizeTransition(
          child: Container(
            width: 200.0,
            height: 200.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            parent: _controller,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

For instance, the following code does not work for `SizeTransition`, but works for `ScaleTransition`. I have no idea what's wrong with `SizeTransition`.

```dart
return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
```

Comment: is your goal to center it horizontally / vertically, or both?

Comment: @George thanks a lot for the reply. I want to center it horizontally. I will update the question. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the fact that my previous answer solves the problem to some extent, I also wanted to address how limited `SizeTransition` widget is and how to solve this.

SizeTransition provides the effect of "unfolding" its content, running the animation either in horizontal or in vertical axis by rewriting alignment settings.

To achieve the same effect without breaking alignment rules, but also avoid using `ScaleTransition` widget as we need the "unfold/reveal" animation and not "scale up" - here is what I propose:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final _animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      // ...,
      AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animation,
        builder: (_, child) => ClipRect(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            heightFactor: _animation.value,
            widthFactor: null,
            child: child,
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text("test"),
        ),
      )
    ]
  );
}
```

This is basically an `AnimatedBuilder` widget with the same `ClipRect` & `Align` used as in `SizeTransition`, except that it does limit alignment to one axis only.

---

If you'd like the animation to run in both horizontal & vertical axes - assign the same `_animation.value` to `widthFactor` property:

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  heightFactor: _animation.value,
  widthFactor: _animation.value,
  child: child,
),
```

This will help you achieve "reveal from center" effect without scaling up & down the content of your widget.

Comment: Very cool. I have upvoted this answer too. So now there is one problem. Which answer do you want me to mark as the final answer? ^_^ The first answer is talking about `SizeTransition` which is the title's keyword. And the second answer solves the problem completely but without using `SizeTransition`. So which one do you prefer? I am OK with both. Thank you very much for your help and time. 

Comment: @sgon00 I‘m glad this helped! Haha well, since this answer eliminates the problem completely and the question is originally about SizeTransition being faulty, I think the solution in this answer is the one I’d recommend using for anyone with similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you tried many things already, here is some ideas I have:

#1

```dart
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: // ...
)
```

or

#2

```dart
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, // critical
  children: <Widget>[
    // ...,
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center, // critical
      child: SizeTransition(
        child: Container(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          parent: _controller,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ]
)
```

---

## Update

There is indeed a peculiar aspect of `SizeTransition` widget.

It has `axis` property that is set to `Axis.vetical` by default, which overrides the widget's horizontal alignment to `-1.0` (start) and vertical alignment to `0.0` (center).

Changing that property to `Axis.horizontal` makes things work the other way around - aligning the widget horizontally to `0.0` (center) and vertically to `-1.0` (start).

Solution:

```dart
SizeTransition(
  axis: Axis.horizontal,
  // ...,
)
```

Please let me know if this helped.

Comment: Hi, I think you didn't test the code. First, `CrossAxisAlignment.center` is the default behavior, so no need to try. But I tried anyway. Unfortunately, both ideas don't work in my test...

Comment: That works. But the size transition behavior changes. The size changes horizontally instead of vertically. So I am wondering if there is a way to keep vertical transition and centered horizontally... Thank you very much for the solution. I have upvoted your answer. I will mark it the final answer if there is no better solution to keep the vertical transition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using animated list view, you can use slide transition instead, just wrap your column around a slide transition widget and you should be good to go

```
SlideTransition(
   position: Tween<Offset>(
     begin: const Offset(0, -1), //The animated item will move upwards, use +1 to move downwards
     end: Offset.zero,
   ).animate(
     CurvedAnimation(parent: widget.animation, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
   ),
   child: Column()
)
```

widget.animation is your `Animation<double>` variable (if inside stateful widget)